# How do I write a graphql-tag when the data is only returning a Boolean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-tag

The server end is using REST to return on a true or a false. How do write a graphql-tag on this?

this is what the server returns : { true }

I tried:

```
const GET_ACCESS = gql`
  query getAccess {
    access @rest(type: "access", method: "GET" path: "/access") {
      access
    }
  }
`
```

But nothing is returned, as my json object is not {access: true} it just { true }

Comment: try without body? If the response from your graphql is a boolean you don't have to provide a body.

Comment: Do you mean:
 query getAccess {
    access @rest(type: "access", method: "GET" path: "/access") 
  }

Comment: simply `access @rest(...)` ... without sub-properties/object body